# Module not found: './app.module.ngfactory' i while build iOS app --prod --release

Tags: ios, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I have developed one app in Ionic and while I try to deploy my app with --prod its throwing below error and without --prod its working fine.

Command : `sudo ionic cordova build ios --release --prod`

Error :

> Error: ./src/app/main.ts
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './app.module.ngfactory' in
>   '/Volumes/DATA/Dhanesh/Projects/FA
>   app/TestNewCordova/failure_analysis_app/Ionic/src/app' resolve
>   './app.module.ngfactory' in '/Volumes/DATA/Dhanesh/Projects/FA
>   app/TestNewCordova/failure_analysis_app/Ionic/src/app'   using
>   description file: /Volumes/DATA/Dhanesh/Projects/FA
>   app/TestNewCordova/failure_analysis_app/Ionic/package.json (relative
>   path: ./src/app)
>       Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration   after using description file: /Volumes/DATA/Dhanesh/Projects/FA
>   app/TestNewCordova/failure_analysis_app/Ionic/package.json (relative
>   path: ./src/app)
>       using description file: /Volumes/DATA/Dhanesh/Projects/FA app/TestNewCordova/failure_analysis_app/Ionic/package.json (relative
>   path: ./src/app/app.module.ngfactory)
>         no extension

While if I remove --prod and just run `sudo ionic cordova build ios --release`

and without fail it build successfully.

I found many solution for above error but still didn't got any luck to come out from this error.

Ref I tried so far :

1. Try to find error in `$ ./node_modules/.bin/ngc` but there is no error log over there.
2. Some post on github also not working https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8858

Help me if nay one solved same problem with ionic build ios.

Thanks in advance!

Edit :

```
main.ts

import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core'; 

enableProdMode();

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Comment: I also faced this problem. Can i know what is your ionic/app-script version and also what version of angular you are using

Comment: from where I can find this version can you please guide me ?

Comment: from root folder there will be package.json file. just copy and paste that file

Comment: Ok got it here is my ionic script version : "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.1.2"

Comment: ok just upgrade the ionic app script using **npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest --save-dev**  and check once again run build using --prod flag and make sure that angular is in production mode in main.ts file

Comment: Great as and when I update this script Now I am getting proper error where its actually failed to build thanks Abinesh please post this as answer so it will help other who got the same error like me Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just upgrade the ionic app script using npm install **@ionic/app-scripts@latest --save-dev** and check once again run build using --prod flag

Comment: one more question what do you mean by `make sure that angular is in production mode in main.ts file`

Comment: you need to enable production mode in main.ts file you need to do `import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core'; enableProdMode();`

Comment: after adding enableProdMode() again i am in same issue with building prod with all above error

Comment: can you show your main.ts file or can you update in stack blitz

Comment: do you run with **ionic cordova build ios --prod --release** command. I don't know  why its throwing error for you and what is your angular version.

Comment: enableProdMode() is required but now I solved my problem by updating node thanks for your support and quick reply on my questions.